Issue binding different observable objects within each TabViewItem.Content C# Xamarin Forms
The issue: When the Binding Context of summaryview is summaryviewmodel all of my pickers are empty in the view with no data. When I change the summary view binding context to CyclingViewModel all of the pickers load fine.
Currently I am only able to load data into my view from one tab.
I have created an absolute layout view that is called summaryview that contains a Tabview.
Summaryview has a view model named summaryviewmodel.
My TabView has six TabViewItems each with its own TabViewItemContent.
Each item content is an AbsoluteLayout view with its own viewModel.
XAML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<appPage:AppView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:synopsis="clr-namespace:UI.Synopsis"
             xmlns:appPage="clr-namespace:UI.AppPage"
             xmlns:pgSettings="clr-namespace:UI.PgSettings"
             xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
             x:Class="UI.Synopsis.SummaryView">


        <xct:TabView
            TranslationX="772"
            WidthRequest="284"
            HeightRequest="800"
            TabStripHeight="70"
            TabStripBorderColor="Black"
            BackgroundColor="#C7C9CC"
            IsTabTransitionEnabled="True" TabStripPlacement="Top"
            BindingContext="{Binding CyclingViewModel}" //loads with this line but will not load with this line removed 
        >
            <xct:TabViewItem
             Icon="homeU.png"
             IconSelected="homeSel.png"
             IsEnabled="True" IsVisible="True"
            TabTapped="Home_TabTapped"
            >
                <xct:TabViewItem.Content >
                    <appPage:ImplantInfo TranslationX="0" TranslationY="46"   />
                </xct:TabViewItem.Content>
            </xct:TabViewItem>

            <xct:TabViewItem
            Icon="cyclingU.png"
            IconSelected="cycleSel.png"
            TabTapped="Cycle_TabTapped"
            >
                <xct:TabViewItem.Content>
                    <appPage:CycleConfiguration TranslationX="0" TranslationY="43" HeightRequest="450" BindingContext="{Binding CyclingViewModel}" />
                </xct:TabViewItem.Content>

            </xct:TabViewItem>

            <xct:TabViewItem
            Icon="ratioU.png"
            IconSelected="ratioSel.png"
            Style="{StaticResource CustomTabStyle}"
            TabTapped="Ratio_TabTapped"
            >
                <xct:TabViewItem.Content>
                    <appPage:RatioView TranslationX="0" TranslationY="46" BindingContext="{Binding RatioVModel}" />
                </xct:TabViewItem.Content>
            </xct:TabViewItem>

            <xct:TabViewItem
             Icon="IphU.png"
            IconSelected="IphSel.png"
            Style="{StaticResource CustomTabStyle}"
            >
                <xct:TabViewItem.Content>
                    <appPage:InterPhase TranslationX="0" TranslationY="36"  />
                </xct:TabViewItem.Content>
            </xct:TabViewItem>

            <xct:TabViewItem
            Icon="IpuU.png"
            IconSelected="IpuSel.png"
           Style="{StaticResource CustomTabStyle}"
            >
                <xct:TabViewItem.Content>
                    <appPage:InterPulse TranslationX="0" TranslationY="36"  />
                </xct:TabViewItem.Content>
            </xct:TabViewItem>
            <xct:TabViewItem

             Icon="rampU.png"
            IconSelected="rampSel.png"
            Style="{StaticResource CustomTabStyle}"
            >
                <xct:TabViewItem.Content>
                    <appPage:RampView TranslationX="0" TranslationY="46"  />
                </xct:TabViewItem.Content>
            </xct:TabViewItem>
        </xct:TabView >
   

</appPage:AppView>

CodeBehind
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class SummaryView : AppPage.AppView
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The summary view model.
        /// </summary>
        SummaryViewModel ViewModel;
        /// <summary>
        /// Default Constructor
        /// </summary>
        public SummaryView()
        {

            InitializeComponent();


            try
            {
                ViewModel = new SummaryViewModel();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                NuDebug.WriteLine("Exception thrown constructing SummaryViewModel");
                NuDebug.Dump(e);
                throw;
            }

            try
            {

                BindingContext = ViewModel;

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                NuDebug.WriteLine("Exception thrown setting SummaryViewModel as BindingContext");
                NuDebug.Dump(e);
                throw;
            }

        }
     }

ViewModel
 class SummaryViewModel : PropertyManager, IStimControl
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the cycleConfig.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The CycleConfigViewModel devices.</value>
        //
        public CycleConfigurationViewModel CyclingViewModel { get; set; } = new CycleConfigurationViewModel();
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the cycleConfig.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The CycleConfigViewModel devices.</value>
        ///
        public RatioViewModel RatioVModel { get; set; } = new RatioViewModel();
        public SummaryViewModel()
        {
              LoadCycleData();
              LoadRatioData();
        }

      }

For this problem I will just refer to one of the six because they all have the same setup and issue.
I have AbsoluteLayout view named CyclingConfiguration and its view model is named CyclingConfigurationViewModel.
CyclingConfiguration is a group of pickers and a switch.
Inside my summaryviewmodel class there is a property of type CyclingConfigurationViewModel named CyclingViewModel.
XAML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<AbsoluteLayout
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Controls;assembly=Controls"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UI.AppPage"
    xmlns:xct="clr-namespace:Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.Core;assembly=Xamarin.CommunityToolkit"
    xmlns:xct1="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
    x:Class="UI.AppPage.CycleConfiguration">
    

    
    <AbsoluteLayout.BindingContext>
        <local:CycleConfigurationViewModel/>
    </AbsoluteLayout.BindingContext>


    <Label Text="Cycle Configuration" TranslationX="0" TranslationY="10"  FontSize="20" TextColor="{StaticResource ProminentTextColorLightBackground}" />

    <controls:NuSwitch  x:Name="cActiveSwitch" TranslationX="200" TranslationY="10" HeightRequest="31" WidthRequest="51"  NuTintColor="{StaticResource StrengthColor}"
                       IsToggled="{Binding SelectedCycleEnabled,Mode=TwoWay}" AutomationId="CyclingActive" 
                       >
        
        <controls:NuSwitch.Behaviors>
             <xct1:EventToCommandBehavior
            EventName="Toggled"
            Command="{Binding StimEnabledSelectedCommand}" />
        </controls:NuSwitch.Behaviors>

        </controls:NuSwitch>
         
    <Picker  x:Name="StartTimePicker" TranslationX="0" TranslationY="40"
       IsEnabled="True" ItemsSource="{Binding StartTimerStrings}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedCyclingConfigIndex}" >

        <Picker.Behaviors>
             <xct1:EventToCommandBehavior
            EventName="SelectedIndexChanged"
            Command="{Binding NewTimerSelectedCommand}" />
        </Picker.Behaviors>

        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#111111" />
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#858585" />
                <!--<Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Gray" />-->
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                  
</Picker>

    <Label  Text="Start Time" TranslationX="0" TranslationY="80"  FontSize="16" TextColor="{StaticResource ProminentTextColorLightBackground}"  />

    <StackLayout  TranslationX="0" TranslationY="105" WidthRequest="159" HeightRequest="154">
        
        
        
        <TimePicker x:Name="_timePicker" 
                    IsEnabled="{Binding Source={x:Reference cActiveSwitch},Path=IsToggled} "
                    Time="{Binding SelectedTimeSpan, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    Format="T"
                    PropertyChanged="_timePicker_PropertyChanged"
                     >
 
        </TimePicker>
    </StackLayout>

     <!--Visual Separator-->
    <BoxView  Color="{StaticResource SynopsisSeparator}" WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="2" TranslationX="2" TranslationY="145"/>

    
    <!--Stim On Duration-->
     <Label  Text="Stim On Duration" TranslationX="0" TranslationY="155"  FontSize="16" TextColor="{StaticResource ProminentTextColorLightBackground}" />

        <Label  Text="Hour" TranslationX="0" TranslationY="185"  FontSize="16" TextColor="{StaticResource ProminentTextColorLightBackground}" />
        <Picker  x:Name="onHours" TranslationX="0" TranslationY="205" IsEnabled="{Binding Source={x:Reference cActiveSwitch},Path=IsToggled}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStimOnHour,Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding StartTimeHours}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedHourOnIndex}"
        >
        <Picker.Behaviors>
             <xct1:EventToCommandBehavior
            EventName="SelectedIndexChanged"
            Command="{Binding StimOnHourSelectedCommand}" />
        </Picker.Behaviors>
 

</Picker>

        <Label  Text="Minute" TranslationX="75" TranslationY="185"  FontSize="16" TextColor="{StaticResource ProminentTextColorLightBackground}" />
        <Picker  x:Name="onMinute" TranslationX="75" TranslationY="205" IsEnabled="{Binding Source={x:Reference cActiveSwitch},Path=IsToggled}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStimOnMinutes,Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding StartTimeMinutes}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedMinuteOnIndex}" 
        >
  
        <Picker.Behaviors>
             <xct1:EventToCommandBehavior
            EventName="SelectedIndexChanged"
            Command="{Binding StimOnMinuteSelectedCommand}" />
        </Picker.Behaviors>
</Picker>

    <Label  Text="Seconds" TranslationX="150" TranslationY="185"  FontSize="16" TextColor="{StaticResource ProminentTextColorLightBackground}" />
        <Picker  x:Name="onSeconds" TranslationX="150" TranslationY="205" IsEnabled="{Binding Source={x:Reference cActiveSwitch},Path=IsToggled}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStimOnSeconds,Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding StartTimeSeconds}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedSecondOnIndex}"
        >

        <Picker.Behaviors>
             <xct1:EventToCommandBehavior
            EventName="SelectedIndexChanged"
            Command="{Binding StimOnSecondsSelectedCommand}" />
        </Picker.Behaviors>
  
 
</Picker>

<!--Stim Off Duration-->
    <Label  Text="Stim Off Duration" TranslationX="0" TranslationY="245"  FontSize="16" TextColor="{StaticResource ProminentTextColorLightBackground}" />


        <Label  Text="Hour" TranslationX="0" TranslationY="275"  FontSize="16" TextColor="{StaticResource ProminentTextColorLightBackground}" />
        <Picker  x:Name="offHours" TranslationX="0" TranslationY="295" IsEnabled="{Binding Source={x:Reference cActiveSwitch},Path=IsToggled}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStimOffHour,Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding StartTimeHours}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedHourOffIndex}"
        >
        <Picker.Behaviors>
             <xct1:EventToCommandBehavior
            EventName="SelectedIndexChanged"
            Command="{Binding StimOffHourSelectedCommand}" />
        </Picker.Behaviors>
</Picker>

        <Label  Text="Minute" TranslationX="75" TranslationY="275"  FontSize="16" TextColor="{StaticResource ProminentTextColorLightBackground}" />
        <Picker  x:Name="offMinute" TranslationX="75" TranslationY="295" IsEnabled="{Binding Source={x:Reference cActiveSwitch},Path=IsToggled}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStimOffMinutes,Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding StartTimeMinutes}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedMinuteOffIndex}"
        >
        <Picker.Behaviors>
             <xct1:EventToCommandBehavior
            EventName="SelectedIndexChanged"
            Command="{Binding StimOffMinuteSelectedCommand}" />
        </Picker.Behaviors>
</Picker>

    <Label  Text="Seconds" TranslationX="150" TranslationY="275"  FontSize="16" TextColor="{StaticResource ProminentTextColorLightBackground}" />
        <Picker  x:Name="offSeconds" TranslationX="150" TranslationY="295" IsEnabled="{Binding Source={x:Reference cActiveSwitch},Path=IsToggled}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStimOffSeconds,Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding StartTimeSeconds}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedSecondOffIndex}"
        >
        <Picker.Behaviors>
             <xct1:EventToCommandBehavior
            EventName="SelectedIndexChanged"
            Command="{Binding StimOffSecondsSelectedCommand}" />
        </Picker.Behaviors>
</Picker>

    <!--Number of Cycles-->
    <Label  Text="Number of Cycles" TranslationX="0" TranslationY="335"  FontSize="16" TextColor="{StaticResource ProminentTextColorLightBackground}" />
        <Picker  x:Name="cycles" TranslationX="0" TranslationY="355" IsEnabled="{Binding Source={x:Reference cActiveSwitch},Path=IsToggled}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNumberOfCycles,Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionNumberOfCycles}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedNumCycleIndex}"
        >
        <Picker.Behaviors>
             <xct1:EventToCommandBehavior
            EventName="SelectedIndexChanged"
            Command="{Binding NumberOfCyclesSelectedCommand}" />
        </Picker.Behaviors>
</Picker>

    <controls:NuButton x:Name="SaveButton" TranslationX="20" TranslationY="400" WidthRequest="122" HeightRequest="46"  Text="Save" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="20"
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" AutomationId="SaveButton" IsEnabled="{Binding Source={x:Reference cActiveSwitch},Path=IsToggled}"
                       EnabledBackgroundColor="{StaticResource StrengthBarStartColor}" TextColor="{StaticResource ProminentTextColorLightBackground}"
                       DisabledBackgroundColor="{StaticResource ButtonDisableGrey}" DisabledTextColor="{StaticResource ButtonDisabledTextGrey}"
                       PressedBackgroundColor="{StaticResource ButtonClickedBrown}" Clicked="SaveButton_Clicked" />
    <!--Visual Separator-->
    <BoxView  Color="{StaticResource SynopsisSeparator}" WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="2" TranslationX="2" TranslationY="450"/>
       
</AbsoluteLayout>

CodeBehind
public partial class CycleConfiguration : AbsoluteLayout
    {
      
        public CycleConfiguration()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CycleModel = new CycleConfigurationViewModel();
            CycleModel = (CycleConfigurationViewModel)BindingContext;
        }
       
        protected override void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

            if(propertyName == "StartTimePicker")
            {
                bool enabled = StartTimePicker.IsEnabled;
                int index = StartTimePicker.SelectedIndex;
               
            }
        }
       
        public bool ValidateStartTime()
        {
            bool enabled = StartTimePicker.IsEnabled;
            int index = StartTimePicker.SelectedIndex;
            if(index != -1 && enabled)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
            
        }
       
        void _timePicker_PropertyChanged(System.Object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            if(BindingContext == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            string cycleModelString = "UI.AppPage.CycleConfigurationViewModel";
            string summaryViewModelString = "UI.Synopsis.SummaryViewModel";
            if( BindingContext.ToString() == summaryViewModelString)
            {
                Synopsis.SummaryViewModel summaryViewModel = BindingContext as Synopsis.SummaryViewModel;
                CycleModel = summaryViewModel.CyclingViewModel;
            }
            else
            {
                CycleModel = (CycleConfigurationViewModel)BindingContext;
            }
            
            if (e.PropertyName == "Time")
            {
                CycleModel.InitialTimeSpanSelected();
            }
        }

        
        /// <summary>
        /// Called when user selects save button and while the button is active. Saves Cycling configuration and sends to stimulator.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">Save button </param>
        /// <param name="e">event arguments sent with save button</param>
        void SaveButton_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            //CycleConfigurationViewModel CycleModel; 
            CycleModel = (CycleConfigurationViewModel)BindingContext;
            System.Threading.Tasks.Task task = CycleModel.SaveButtonClickedAsync();
        }
    }

ViewModel:
 public partial class CycleConfigurationViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// cycling enabled property at least first cycling is on
        /// </summary>
        [ObservableProperty]
        public bool cyclingEnabled;
        /// <summary>
        /// startTimeEnabled property current start time that gets enabled 
        /// </summary>
        [ObservableProperty]
        public bool startTimeEnabled;
        /// <summary>
        /// Collection of cycle model configurations per cycle.
        /// </summary>
        [ObservableProperty]
        public ObservableCollection<CyclingConfigModel> cycleModelCollection  = new ObservableCollection<CyclingConfigModel>();
        
        /// <summary>
        /// currently selectedStimOnHour Value
        /// </summary>
        [ObservableProperty]
        public int selectedStimOnHour;
        /// <summary>
        /// currently selectedHourOnIndex value for the picker to start at initialized value Value
        /// </summary>
        [ObservableProperty]
        public int selectedHourOnIndex;
        /// <summary>
        /// currently selectedStimOnMinute Value
        /// </summary>
        [ObservableProperty]
        public int selectedStimOnMinutes;
        /// <summary>
        /// currently selectedMinuteOnIndex value for the picker to start at initialized value Value
        /// </summary>
        [ObservableProperty]
        public int selectedMinuteOnIndex;
        /// <summary>
        /// currently selectedStimOnSecond Value
        /// </summary>
        [ObservableProperty]
        public int selectedStimOnSeconds;
        /// <summary>
        /// currently selectedSecondOnIndex value for the picker to start at initialized value Value
        /// </summary>
        [ObservableProperty]
        public int selectedSecondOnIndex;
        /// <summary>
        /// currently selectedStimOffHour Value
        /// </summary>
        [ObservableProperty]
        public int selectedStimOffHour;
        /// <summary>
        /// currently selectedHourOffIndex value for the picker to start at initialized value Value
        /// </summary>
        [ObservableProperty]
        public int selectedHourOffIndex;
        /// <summary>
        /// currently selectedStimOffMinute Value
        /// </summary>
        [ObservableProperty]
        public int selectedStimOffMinutes;
        /// <summary>
        /// currently selectedMinuteOffIndex value for the picker to start at initialized value Value
        /// </summary>
        [ObservableProperty]
        public int selectedMinuteOffIndex;
        /// <summary>
        /// currently selectedStimOffSecond Value
        /// </summary>
        [ObservableProperty]
        public int selectedStimOffSeconds;
        /// <summary>
        /// currently selectedSecondOffIndex value for the picker to start at initialized value Value
        /// </summary>
        [ObservableProperty]
        public int selectedSecondOffIndex;
        /// <summary>
        /// currently selectedNumberOfCycles Value
        /// </summary>
        [ObservableProperty]
        public int selectedNumberOfCycles;
        /// <summary>
        /// currently selectedNumCycleIndex value for the picker to start at initialized value Value
        /// </summary>
        [ObservableProperty]
        public int selectedNumCycleIndex;
        /// <summary>
        /// currently selectedCycleEnabled Value
        /// </summary>
        [ObservableProperty]
        public bool selectedCycleEnabled;
        /// <summary>
        /// currently selectedTimeSpan value that current UI starttime is set to.
        /// </summary>
        [ObservableProperty]
        public TimeSpan selectedTimeSpan;
        /// <summary>
        /// Collection of strings that are used for the schedule selections
        /// </summary>
        [ObservableProperty]
        public ObservableCollection<string> startTimerStrings  = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        /// <summary>
        /// Collection of ints that are used for the hour selections box
        /// </summary>
        [ObservableProperty]
        public ObservableCollection<int> startTimeHours = new ObservableCollection<int>();
        /// <summary>
        /// Collection of ints that are used for the minutes selections box
        /// </summary>
        [ObservableProperty]
        public ObservableCollection<int> startTimeMinutes = new ObservableCollection<int>();
        /// <summary>
        /// Collection of ints that are used for the seconds selections box
        /// </summary>
        [ObservableProperty]
        public ObservableCollection<int> startTimeSeconds = new ObservableCollection<int>();
        /// <summary>
        /// Collection of bools that are used for the enabling selected schedules s
        /// </summary>
        [ObservableProperty]
        public ObservableCollection<bool> startTimesEnabled = new ObservableCollection<bool>();
        /// <summary>
        /// Collection of ints that are used for the number of cycles selections box
        /// </summary>
        [ObservableProperty]
        public ObservableCollection<int> collectionNumberOfCycles = new ObservableCollection<int>();
        /// <summary>
        /// Collection of TimeSpan values that are used for the each start time 
        /// </summary>
        [ObservableProperty]
        public ObservableCollection<TimeSpan> collectionOfTimeSpans = new ObservableCollection<TimeSpan>();
        /// <summary>
        /// int of the currenlty selected cycling index
        /// </summary>
        [ObservableProperty]
        public int selectedCyclingConfigIndex = 0;
        /// <summary>
        /// bool set to true when we are loading values from stimulator
        /// </summary>
        private bool Reloading;

       
        public CycleConfigurationViewModel()
        {
            ReloadingFromXpg = false;
            CyclingEnabled = false;
            StartTimerStrings.Add("Start Time 1");
            CycleModelCollection.Add(new CyclingConfigModel());
            StartTimesEnabled.Add(true);
            CollectionOfTimeSpans.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0));
            SelectedCyclingConfigIndex = 0;
            if (CollectionNumberOfCycles.Count > 0)
            {
                CollectionNumberOfCycles.Clear();
            }
            for (int h = 0; h < numberOfHoursPerDay; ++h)
            {
                StartTimeHours.Add(h);

            }
            for (int m = 0; m < numberOfMinutesPerHour; ++m)
            {
                StartTimeMinutes.Add(m);

            }
            for (int s = 0; s < numberOfSecondsPerMinute; ++s)
            {
                StartTimeSeconds.Add(s);

            }
            for (int n = 1; n < totalNumberOfCycles; ++n)
            {
                CollectionNumberOfCycles.Add(n);

            }
            SelectedHourOnIndex = 0;
            SelectedNumberOfCycles = 1;
            SelectedHourOnIndex = 0;
            SelectedMinuteOnIndex = 0;
            SelectedSecondOnIndex = 0;
            SelectedHourOffIndex = 0;
            SelectedMinuteOffIndex = 0;
            SelectedSecondOffIndex = 0;
            SelectedNumCycleIndex = 0;
        }

Any help with how to setup binding properly for my data is appreciated.
